# What is meant by the "collar of a disk"?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've seen people use the term "collar of a disk" within the context of algebraic topology.  What is meant by this term?  Is it the "boundary" of a disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the boundary cross an interval open on one side, equivalently a small open neighborhood of the boundary.

Comment: So if $U$ denotes an open disk, and $B$ denotes an open ball centered somewhere on the boundary of $U$, then we have that $U \cap B$ is a collar of $U$?

Comment: I don't think that quite does it-you need an open neighborhood of the entire boundary, not just part of it. So for instance $B(1/2,(0,1))\cap B(1,(0,0))$ is not a collar of the unit disk $B(1,(0,0))$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, whereas $\{x:1/2<|x|< 1\}$ is. (Here $B(r,c)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ around the point $c$.)

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Just to check my understanding: let now $U$ be an open set and $u \in U$.  Is $U - \{u\}$ a collar of $U$?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see that terminology used for an arbitrary open $U$. For an open disk, yes, that's a fine collar.