# Collars of a manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, quotient-spaces

- How is the collar of a oriented smooth manifold $M$ with boundary defined?
  Is it simply a topological space $C$ such that $C= \partial M \times [a,b)$ with product topology and $a <b$, as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790810/what-is-meant-by-the-collar-of-a-disk) answer somehow states?
- Two oriented manifolds with boundary can be glued together along their common boundary (see "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" by John Lee for details). My lecture notes state that, if you want to glue two **smooth** oriented manifolds with boundary together and obtain a **smooth** manifold, "choices like collars are necessary." How so?

Comment: A collar of a (non-necessarily oriented) smooth manifold with boundary is the image of an embedding $\varphi:[a,b)\times \partial M\to M$ such that $\varphi|_{\{a\}\times\partial M}=\mathrm{id}_{\partial M}$, so it is more than the simple manifold with boundary $[a,b)\times\partial M$.

Comment: Gluing together topological manifolds along boundaries can be done with just the quotient topology (though it might be worth verifying that the result is a topological manifold). For smooth manifolds, one must specify a smooth structure on the quotient space, and collars give a straightforward way of doing this. Theorem 9.29 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* goes through the details of this construction.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If one of you could post their comment as a answer, I could accept it. Then this question would not be appear in  "unaswered".